# json_normalize: AttributeError list obj has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, normalize

I'm working with JSON data from an API response. I'm using python to send a GET request with data on an address. I want to capture the JSON response and convert to a dataframe.

Currently I capture the responses in a list of dictionaries. I can successfully use json_normalize on r.json or sample_list[0], but cannot normalize the entire list. I'm trying to avoid creating and appending the df in the loop for performance.

```
sample_list = []
for index, row in sample_df.iterrows():
    sample_address = json.dumps(
        {       
            "records": [
                {
                    "attributes": {
                    "OBJECTID": row['OBJECTID'],
                    "Address": row['Address'],
                    "City": row['City'],
                    "Region": row['Region'],
                    "Postal": row['Postal']
                }
                }
            ]
        }
        )

    r = re.get(url, params = { 'addresses': sample_address, 'f':'pjson'},verify = False)

    sample_list.append(r.json()['locations'])

###The Output of r.json for one address

{'locations': [{'address': '2600 Benjamin Franklin Pkwy, Philadelphia, Pennsylvania, 19130',..., 'score': 100}], 'spatialReference': {'latestWkid': 4326, 'wkid': 4326}}

###The sample_list of multiple r.json output
[[{'address': '520 Chestnut St, Philadelphia, Pennsylvania, 19106',
   'attributes': {'AddNum': '520',
   ...},
   'location': {'x': -75.14971142634045, 'y': 39.94905972672609},
   'score': 100}],
 [{'address': '2600 Benjamin Franklin Pkwy, Philadelphia, Pennsylvania, 19130',
   'attributes': {'AddNum': '2600',
    ...,
   'location': {'x': -75.17923104567541, 'y': 39.96474536190999},
   'score': 100}]]
```

Comment: Correction - I can successfully use json_normalize on r.json['locations'] to achieve desired output, not on r.json .

Comment: To resolve, I changed FROM: sample_list.append(r.json()['locations']) TO: sample_list.append(json_normalize(r.json()['locations']))  and then can use pd.concat(sample_list) to create a single dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sample_list.append(r.json()['locations']) just try 'json_normalize' instead of 'r.json'.

Comment: Thanks! This is much closer. I'm assuming you meant: 

FROM: 
sample_list.append(r.json()['locations'])

TO:
sample_list.append(json_normalize(r.json()['locations']))

I'm trying to make sense of the output. Each list item looks like a row of a dataframe. How would I convert to a single dataframe?

Comment: Nevermind - asking the question helped me think of the answer: pd.concat(sample_list)